# PHPUnit tests fail on writing file

Tags: phpunit, travis-ci

My unit tests are failing on Travis CI, but not locally.

https://travis-ci.org/humanmade/backupwordpress/jobs/43609663#L362

Error message:

```
1) testBackupPathTestCase::testMergeExistingPath
RuntimeException: Error writing to file. (/tmp/wordpress/wp-content/backupwordpress-   a74dcf0e84-backups/.schedule-test-merge-existing-path-running)
```

Test is here:

https://github.com/humanmade/backupwordpress/blob/hmbkp-path/tests/other/testBackupPath.php#L135

That exception is thrown by the following function:

```
/**
 * Set the status of the running backup
 *
 * @access public
 *
 * @param string $message
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function set_status( $message ) {

    $status = json_encode( (object) array(
        'filename' => $this->get_archive_filename(),
        'started'  => $this->get_schedule_running_start_time(),
        'status'   => $message,
    ) );

    if ( false === @file_put_contents( $this->get_schedule_running_path(), $status ) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( sprintf( __( 'Error writing to file. (%s)', 'backpwordpress' ), $this->get_schedule_running_path() ) );
    }

}
```

See full class here :

https://github.com/humanmade/backupwordpress/blob/hmbkp-path/classes/class-schedule.php#L838

How can I determine if it's an error caused by the CI environment, or a bug in the code?

Comment: Looks like you solved it? It would be great if you could self-answer.

Comment: it kind of fixed itself, not sure how sorry